# Why are some of my pictures all black?

Tags: camera

I was out on a hike today and took a few pictures. When taking a picture I saw the usual animation where I see snapshot of the picture just taken, and then it slides away from the screen to display the camera viewfinder again. After coming home I notice this in my google photos: [image]

What causes this to happen?

Comment: Any chance your finger was over the lens?

Comment: This happens to me when the camera accidentally gets activated in my pocket.

Comment: Are there any photos you made but there are not here?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if this is an issue where the camera got activated in a dark place, such as your pocket. Undue pressure (false touches) can cause this, or even if the camera app took 2 pictures in burst mode (it isn't supposed to happen, but it does anyway). There can also be other issues which may rarely be for to a hardware problem, but since this is not a major problem I don't think it merits a service center visit.